# How to generate a DataFrame with some content and N rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to generate a dataframe with these column values

```
   A , B , C
   1,  b1, c1
   2,  b2 , c2
   3,  b3,  c3
```

I need to generate 1000 rows in the dataframe and everytime when a new row is being generated the value in Colum A should increment

I used this code

`val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq.fill(200){(colA+1,colB+1)}).toDF("col1","col2")`

how to increment the column values everytime when a new row is added i either scala or java ?.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = (1 to 100).map(n => (n, s"b$n",s"c$n"))
  .toDF("A","B","C")
```

which will give:

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1| b1| c1|
|  2| b2| c2|
|  3| b3| c3|
|  4| b4| c4|
|  5| b5| c5|
|  6| b6| c6|
|  7| b7| c7|
|  8| b8| c8|
|  9| b9| c9|
| 10|b10|c10|
+---+---+---+
```

Instead of `1 to 100`, you can also use `Seq.range(1,100)`, `Seq.tabulate(100)(_ + 1)` or `Seq.iterate(1,100)(_ + 1)`

alternatively without building from a scala collection, namely using `spark.range` which gives a `Dataset[Long]`:

```
val df = spark.range(100)
  .map(n => (n,s"b$n",s"c$n"))
  .toDF("A","B","C")
```

or using `withColumn` and `concat`

```
val df = spark.range(1L,100L).toDF("A")
  .withColumn("B",concat(lit("b"),$"A"))
  .withColumn("C",concat(lit("c"),$"A"))
```

which gives the same result

but

> how to increment the column values everytime when a new row is added i
>   either scala or java ?.

This is quite complicated, I would not recommend to add rows (in a loop) to a dataframe, this would need many `union` and incrementing the last value would need aggregation each time